# Citing a Poem in APA

Tags: citations, poetry, apa

I'm having trouble finding any reputable source online that indicates how to cite a poem in APA, and I don't have access to a physical copy of the APA manual right now. Does anyone know how to cite a poem in APA style?

Specifically, I'd like to cite Robert Burns's "To a Mouse" (http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/43816). [This poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_a_Mouse) was included in the [Kilmarnock volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilmarnock_volume/). I'm having trouble putting together this information in an APA citation.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suspect this answers the question. [Pellissippi State Community College - MLA & APA Citation: Poem](http://lib.pstcc.edu/c.php?g=106731&p=693754) I don't know anything about this site but perhaps someone more familiar with APA can cross check the information?

Comment: @NeilFein, the page you linked is under the MLA section, not the APA. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late for the OP, but in case someone else is curious...

I couldn't find anything specifically about poems, but I think following the style used for a chapter or entry in a book should be fine. That is:

> Author, A. A., & Author, B. B. (1995). Title of chapter or entry. In A. Editor, B. Editor, & C. Editor (Eds.), Title of book (pp. xxx–xxx). Location: Publisher.

In the case of Robert Burns' "To a Mouse", the Kilmarnock volume's title page gives Robert Burns as the author (and no editor), therefore we can cite the poem as:

> Burns, R. (1786). To a Mouse. In R. Burns, *Poems, Chiefly in the Scottish Dialect* (p. 138-140). Kilmarnock: John Wilson.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this tool to refer in APA style (and in any other style): citethisforme.com

Burns, R. & Bohne, P. (1974). *To a mouse, a louse and a mountain daisy*. Rosemead, Calif.: Bookhaven Press.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like that there's a poem option.